# How do I exclude any anchor element from html body text with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 +http://www.google.com/bot.html)").timeout(100000).get();
data.add(doc.body().text());
```

This gives me the text including the hyperlink text or link text but I don't need that. I only want plain text like the text written in `<p>`,`<b>`,etc tags or without any tags.

Comment: have a look at DOM methods such as `.getElementsByTagName()`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove all `a` tags you can simply `select` and `remove` them:

```
doc.select("a").remove();
```

You can append more elements to remove by adding them to the `select`

```
doc.select("a, div, script").remove();
```

Comment: You can speed up the process by focusing the removal on the `body` element only and not the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for(Element e : doc.body().select("*:not(a)")) {
    data.add(e.ownText());
}
```

You can exclude other elements by using a CSS query like below:

```
*:not(a, p, div)
```

Comment: Invoking `text()` on `Elements` (returned by `select`) will return the combined text of an element and its children. So this will likely return element texts multiple times.

Comment: @nyname00 Thanks for pointing out this issue. I have updated my code accordingly.